# Display image after file input selection with image resize

Tags: javascript, image, filereader

I have seen posts asking how to display an image selected via a file input control. When I try these solutions, they work, yet I have a further issue I am unable to discover an answer to on my own: When I select an image for the first time, the image will not display because no image width and height data is available (image data is available via the FileReader obj, yet not the image width and height). The second time the image is selected (or after a reload), the width and height become available. Why is this occurring and what can I do to fix it? thanks.

Here's some code I've been using - this is one of the FileReader functions. I started by using reader.onload, but then thought the image width and height were not available because it hadn't loaded fully yet. Therefore onloadend seemed a better choice. It doesn't work any better here, though:

```
reader.onloadend = function(e) {

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = e.target.result;// or reader.result - doesn't matter

  // A function that does math to proportionally scale the image

  var new_size = scaleImageSize(150, 150, img.width, img.height);

  img.width = new_size[0];
  img.height = new_size[1];

  // And here I am trying both ways to display the image: the first
  // in a div tag, the second straight into an img tag. I only want
  // to use one of these - preferably the div tag. I have also tried
  // drawing the image onto an HTML5 canvas. All to no avail.

  document.getElementById("file_display_area").appendChild(img);
  document.getElementById("img_file_display_area").src = img.src;

  console.log(img.width + '|' + img.height + '||' + new_size[0] + '|' + new_size[1]);

}
```

Comment: Was able to find a solution: img.onload = function() { ... } Seems the filereader.onload (or unloaded) methods were not waiting for the image file to be loaded before running. Only the img.onload method allowed me to get the width and height of the image selected.